# Espressione alternativa a 'angeli del fango'

Tags: word-choice

È noto come in Italia si usi parlare di 'angeli del fango' per definire le persone che volontariamente e con senso civico intervengono a spalare il fango dalle strade a seguito di incredibili alluvioni.

Non ho mai trovato gradevole quest'espressione, sicché sono a chiedere: Come potremmo chiamare queste persone senza ricorrere a perverse forme retoriche?

Comment: Che tipo di espressione stai cercando? Qualcosa che preservi la connotazione eroica? Qualcosa di neutrale?

Comment: @giulio, cercavo un espressione dove si evitasse l'uso del termine 'angeli', magari anche tenendo 'fango'—tipo 'uomini del fango' o anche 'soldati del fango' ( che però non so se hanno la stessa potenza evocativa).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ragazzi di buona volontà...?
O semplicemente volontari?

Mi rifiuto categoricamente di riconoscere una qualunque altra espressione assurdamente retorica, più o meno *religiosamente evocativa* che sia.

Fanno qualcosa di splendido, ma perché (mi auguro) sono (o dovrebbero essere) persone dal grande senso civico e trovo che mitizzarli sia solo una scusa per autogiustificarsi ed esimersi dal fare altrettanto, o qualcos'altro che abbia comunque valore umano e civile.

Comment: Sicuramente "volontario", è anche più vicino allo spirito dei tanti che compiono un servizio sociale, semplicemente sentendo che  è un loro dovere civico.